# How to Sphinxsearch with Group By and Group_Concat?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sphinx

I have a Sphinx-Index-Table with ids, data and datatypes.

```
|    sphinxid    |    objectid    |      data      |     type    |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|-------------|
|        1       |       10       |  Lorem ipsum   |    title    |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|-------------|
|        2       |       10       | dolor si ipsum | description |
|----------------|----------------|----------------|-------------|
|        3       |       20       | dolor sit amet |     date    |
```

Now i try to run a search query similar to this working mysql query:

```
SELECT objectid, GROUP_CONCAT(type) AS types 
FROM SphinxIndex 
WHERE data LIKE '%ipsum%'
GROUP BY objectid
```

Here is my php code using sphinxapi.php

```
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->SetServer("localhost", 9312);
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
    $cl->SetLimits(0, 1000);
    $cl->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
    // THROWS ERR: can not aggregate non-scalar attribute 'datatype'
    $cl->SetSelect("objectid, GROUP_CONCAT(type) AS types");
    //----------------------------------------------
    $cl->SetGroupBy('objectid', SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR, '@count DESC');
    $cl->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@count DESC");
    $searchresults = $cl->Query('*' . 'ipsum' . '*');
```

My expected result was something like this,

```
|    objectid    |      types         |
|----------------|--------------------|
|        10      | title, description |
```

but unfortunately it throws an error:

```
THROWS ERR: can not aggregate non-scalar attribute 'type'
```

I read that multi-valued attribution might be a possible solution for the problem, but i didnt really understand how this is working.

Comment: What is `datatype`? I don't see any datatype in your table.

Comment: its a typo - in my real index table the column is named datatype. edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphinx does not allow you to aggregate over fields that aren't scalars (e.g. integers). I'm assuming that the `type` field is for some kind of a referential value. You could use another table, say `type_dictionary`:

```
1 title
2 desctiption
3 date
```

and use its index in your main table:

```
sphinxid ... type
1            1
2            3
3            2
```

In this case `GROUP_CONCAT` would work.